# How can I get the byte array of an avro GenericRecord?

Tags: c++, serialization, avro

I am trying to get the serialized avro GenericRecord that I populated. I do not want to write the avro to a file, but instead get a byte array that I can pass further.

I actually tried to write using avro::GenericWriter and avro::StreamReader but all I get is a blank 4096 length byte array.

```cpp
avro::ValidSchema recordSchema;
recordSchema = avro::compileJsonSchemaFromString(schemaString);
avro::GenericDatum gd(recordSchema);
avro::GenericDatum result = populateSchema(record, gd);
```

What I've tried:

```cpp
avro::EncoderPtr e = avro::binaryEncoder();
avro::OutputStreamPtr out = avro::memoryOutputStream();
e->init(*out);

avro::GenericWriter writer(recordSchema, e);
writer.write(result);
out->flush();

avro::InputStreamPtr in = avro::memoryInputStream(*out);
avro::StreamReader reader(*in);
size_t outputLen = out->byteCount();
uint8_t* theByteData = new uint8_t[outputLen];
reader.readBytes(theByteData, outputLen);
return (char*)theByteData;
```